# Encrypting a value using MySQL's AES_ECRYPT function, then passing it in a URL string, using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, aes

I need to encrypt a string using MySQL's AES_ENCRYPT function, then attach that encrypted string to the end of a URL, such that it can then be decrypted and used by a PHP script on the other end.

Basically, I am encrypting the string (using MySQL's AES_ENCRYPT), I am then using PHP's rawurlencode() function to make it "URL safe". I then pass the encrypted string in a URL, which is then retrieved by the PHP script on the other end where it gets successfully decrypted... about 95% of the time.

Seems as though about 5% of strings are encrypting in such a way that they are getting corrupted somewhere in the process, and can't be decoded on the other end after being passed by a URL. Can anyone help me out here? Is there a 100% fool-proof way to do this? I have also tried using urlencode() as well as base64_encode() in varying combinations.

Thanks.

Comment: Data samples? Source code? :)

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using MySQL's implementation of AES instead of PHP's?  You probably have support available in the [mcrypt extension](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.ciphers.php) (which calls AES by it's other name, Rijndael).

Comment: After all, it's difficult to figure out why some strings might be glitching unless we can have some idea as to which glitch and which don't.

Comment: @Charles - I imagine he's probably pulling the data straight from the database, anyway.

Comment: I used MySQL because it doesn't seem mcrypt() is a native PHP function, I am passing this variable across multiple servers. Investigating how to install this extension could be an option though.

I'm actually not pulling any data from the database, I'm just doing something like "SELECT AES_ENCRYPT('somevalue', 'somekey')". And this works great 95% of the time.

Providing examples isn't really an option because that would involve divulging the salt (key), and the encrypted string (there's a reason we're encrypting them!).

Comment: @Callum: you do know that using the URL divulges the encrypted string to the world, right?  **If** you're using HTTPS, then the only place you've leaked it is in the webserver logs on the receiving system.  Otherwise, it's available to anyone who can sniff the network connection between the nodes.  Which, if you're going over the Internet at large, is most anyone.

Comment: It seems this is not isolated to a MySQL specific issue, I had the same behaviour with phpseclib AES encrypted strings being passed via http url. The accepted answer below resolved my issue as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.

Once I have encrypted the string using MySQL's AES_ENCRYPT function, I use PHP's bin2hex() function to convert that encrypted data (which is in binary form) in to Hexidecimal. I then pass the Hexidecimal as a string on the end of the URL. Once the URL is received on the other end, I then use this custom PHP function to revert the Hex string back to binary:

```
function hex2bin($data) {
    $len = strlen($data);
    return pack("H" . $len, $data);
}
```

From there, all that's left to do is decrypt the data using MySQL's AES_DECRYPT function, and wha-la. The original string is successfully restored.

Comment: Thank you so much for your question and answer. This has directly solved my problem. Like you, I am passing AES encrypted values over http as querystrings, however I'm not using MySQL's AES encrypt/decrypt functions (or MySQL at all), but rather using the purely php phpseclib AES crypt functions.  So it would seem it's not specific to MySQL, but rather a "AES over http GET" issue.  I'm surprised this hasn't had more hits? It must be a rare occurrence. I had tried every possible combination of urlencode/rawurlencode & decoding etc to no avail. This bin2hex and hex2bin solution worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

URLs have a finite maximum length.  AES-encrypted strings do not.

URLs are not an appropriate vector for passing arbitrary information.  Using an HTTP POST is a much better way, if you must communicate over HTTP.

About why you are having problems: quoting from [the PHP manual page on `urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode):

> Note: Be careful about variables that
>   may match HTML entities. Things like
>   &amp, &copy and &pound are parsed by
>   the browser and the actual entity is
>   used instead of the desired variable
>   name. This is an obvious hassle that
>   the W3C has been telling people about
>   for years. The reference is here:
>   http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#h-B.2.2.
>   PHP supports changing the argument
>   separator to the W3C-suggested
>   semi-colon through the arg_separator
>   .ini directive. Unfortunately most
>   user agents do not send form data in
>   this semi-colon separated format. A
>   more portable way around this is to
>   use `&amp;` instead of & as the
>   separator. You don't need to change
>   PHP's arg_separator for this. Leave it
>   as &, but simply encode your URLs
>   using htmlentities() or
>   htmlspecialchars().

Comment: Thanks for your response, I can confirm that string length is not the problem.